# What are these structures in blood from a nosebleed?

Tags: hematology, microscopy, nose

I decided to look at some blood from a nosebleed (not mine) under the microscope and took some pictures of the results. There many large orange structures interspersed within the blood cells and I'm wondering if someone knowledgeable can tell me what they are? Are they skin cells? What are the fibres inside them?

[image: Picture][image]
[image: x400]

[image]

The first two images are x400 and second one is x100.

Comment: Could you estimate the diameter?

Comment: In the first picture it is roughly 100 microns if I use the RBC as a unit of measurement.

Comment: This is a mere guess: You see accumulations of airborne fibers (dust) that got caught by secreted lipid droplets within your nose.